# Copy of incoming Mail (Mac "Mail" is client) shows up in sent email when email is sent from a php form after migration to g suite

Tags: email, mac-osx, mac, gmail, g-suite

I helped someone migrate their email from a web hosting service because of deliverability issues. Anyway, the migration went well:

- Migrated email
- Set mx records
- Authenticated domain name (SPF and DKIM)
- Implemented DMARC (reporting only for now)
- Added accounts to their Apple Mail and mobile email client

**Email sent from a PHP form that sends an email whenever a new order comes in arrives in both the account inbox but also a copy of it arrives in the subfolder for the *account" user* and the *important* user so it's three places for email. The email is basically an orders notification that summarizes the order so they know there's an order to be fulfilled (it's a physical product that needs to be shipped).**

I helped them do a *rule* that said if *To* contains `orders@` then move to *orders* folder and applied to existing email. It worked on existing email but the rule doesn't run on new orders coming in.

The rule wasn't meant as a permanent solution anyway, but as a stopgap, until I could find the root cause. Any ideas on why this rule doesn't work on new emails? And any ideas on the root cause of this and how to solve it so the email does not show up in 3 folders? It's a lot of clutter is the issue.

### addendum

I've noticed that the form sends from orders@example.com so maybe the reason  this is happening is that is the same address as the account the form submits to. So google thinks that since the email is "From" the same account that's being sent to it thinks it must have sent it so it puts a copy in sent. I think that might be what's happening. Now, I'm wondering if there's a way to work around that so emails "from" the orders@ address are identified only as incoming emails for the inbox not as a sent email as well. Any ideas on a way to do this if my hypothesis makes sense as a possiblity?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I called google tech support and a migration specialist suggested I try migrating with the client application itself (IMAP with Apple Mail). So I tried that, and it worked well.

1. Connect to old account (in this case, a VPS at a web hosting provider), bringing in the email.
2. Connect to new account.
3. Copy email from old to new account.

*Note:* Wait for email to copy and for IMAP to synch before closing client. Also, make sure your laptop's plugged in as data transfer will stall if not plugged in, which is good because if power did fail during data transfer it could result in corrupted data.